# SCCM/MECM or PS: Remote Notification to client

Tags: push-notification, sccm

I am trying to figure out a good way to publish or deploy a notification to a specific list of computers. I have the availability of SCCM/MECM team or if its easier just perform the function via a script as an admin.

The content of what I am doing is to efficiently locate some hardware that needs replaced, the device's locations within the large organization was poorly tracked by employees prior to my arrival, so instead of walking around crawling under desk, I was thinking I could just send a mass notification to the select workstations, informing the users of the device to reach out to me.

I tried to use a WshShell message, but the test have been inconsistant. Some of the test workstations i tried it on received the message, while others just received a message with "msg" only for the text instead of the actual message.

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell -ErrorAction Stop
$wshell.Popup("Your workstation has been detected as end of life. Please call XXX-XXXX to schedule a replacement of your workstation.",0,"Workstation End of Life",0)
```

Comment: You can do this with SCCM (you would have to configure it in a way to only run when a user is present) but keep in mind that if you show this in a script, for the time this is displayed it is not possible to deploy software or updates to the machine because it would be queued behind the execution of your popup. (this can be mitigated by starting the popup in a second process which is started but not waited on by the sccm script). As for why some machines display wrong messages this sounds like a bug of the script and not a sccm related problem to me